# JSP script can't show Arabic characters correctly

Tags: jsp, character-encoding, jsp-tags

When I get the following output:

```
System.out.print(name);
```

I can't see the characters correctly.

How can I fix it?

Here is my code :

**insert.jsp**

```
<%@page import="dao.DaoAdmin"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement;"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");   %>
<%
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
    System.out.print(name);
%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    alert("dsfg");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Sita Ajax test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    function ajaxRequest() {
        var activexmodes = [ "Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" ]; //activeX versions to check for in IE
        if (window.ActiveXObject) { //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
            for ( var i = 0; i < activexmodes.length; i++) {
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i]);
                } catch (e) {
                    //suppress error
                }
            }
        } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            return false;
    }
    // JavaScript Document
    function ajaxget() {
        var mygetrequest = new ajaxRequest();
        mygetrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (mygetrequest.readyState == 4) {

                document.getElementById("insert_response").innerHTML = mygetrequest.responseText;

            }
        };
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

        mygetrequest.open("GET", "insert.jsp?name=" + name + "&city=" + city
                + "&phone=" + phone + "", true);
        mygetrequest.send(null);

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>

    <form action="javascript:ajaxget()" ; method="post"
        accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <table style="background-color: #ECE5B6;" width="30%">

            <tr>
                <th width="50%">Name</th>
                <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50%">City</th>
                <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="city" id="city">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50%">Phone</th>
                <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td width="50%"><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <!-- Show Message for AJAX response -->
    <div id="insert_response"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will help you or not, but I thing I have noticed in your code `insert.jsp` is you are writing this code :

```
<%
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
    System.out.print(name);
%>
```

even before you start your `<html>` code. This code should be somewhere in `<body> ...</body>` tags.

Second, why are you writing multiple `<%@page ..>` tags  with different attributes.

```
<%@page import="dao.DaoAdmin"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement;"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");   %>
```

Instead write it like this :

```
<%@page import="dao.DaoAdmin;java.sql;java.sql.PreparedStatement" language="java"
contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

So try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `response.setCharacterEncoding ("UTF-8");` in the beginning.